# Indentation in the algorithm package after \Ensure, \Require

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

I have this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

   \begin{algorithmic}
      \Require   \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  A \par
                  AA  
               \end{varwidth}
      \Ensure      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  B \par
                  BB
               \end{varwidth}
   \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

I would like the text which follows after `\Ensure` to be indented in such a way that it is placed right under the text which follows after `\Require`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the definition of `\Ensure` to build a box as wide as **Require:**; you can do it globally or locally:

### Global

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{%
  \makebox[\widthof{\textbf{Require:}}][l]{\textbf{Ensure:}}}

\begin{document}

   \begin{algorithmic}
      \Require   \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  A \par
                  AA\strut
               \end{varwidth}
      \Ensure      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  B \par
                  BB\strut
               \end{varwidth}
   \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

### Local

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof

\begin{document}

   \begin{algorithmic}
   \algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{%
     \makebox[\widthof{\textbf{Require:}}][l]{\textbf{Ensure:}}}
      \Require   \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  A \par
                  AA\strut
               \end{varwidth}
      \Ensure      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  B \par
                  BB\strut
               \end{varwidth}
   \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Notice also the `\strut` at the end of `varwidth` to get an even vertical spacing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Is there also a solution local to an algorithm definition (\begin{algorithmic} ... solution ... \end{algorithmic})? My problem is that I have another definition in which 'Ensure' and 'Variables' appear, and in this case 'Ensure' has to be adjusted to the length of 'Variables'.

Comment: @efie You can put the `\algrenewcommand` inside the environment where you want it to hold. I've shown the two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\reqwidth}
\settowidth{\reqwidth}{\textbf{Require:}}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\makebox[\reqwidth][l]{\textbf{Ensure:}}}

   \begin{algorithmic}
      \Require   \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  A \par
                  AA  
               \end{varwidth}
      \Ensure      \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                  B \par
                  BB
               \end{varwidth}
   \end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]